# Unable to get the required output from find commands

Tags: shell

I have two directories ${WEB_HOME}/backup/csvs and  $(WEB_HOME)/home/archives under PURGE_DIR_PATH, basically want to find and delete all the files older than 60 days and compress files greater than 30 days but less than 60 days. The issue I'm facing here is find is not giving me the files from both the directories,
When i echo after for loop and if loop i am able to see both paths(dir_name) getting written into the LOG_FILE but somehow its not looping through properly as in the output i can see log files from only one directory  which is from $(WEB_HOME)/home/archives.

```
#!/bin/bash

export LOG_RETENTION=60
export LOG_COMPRESS=30
export WEB_HOME="/web/local/artifacts"
export CURR_DT=`date +%Y%m%d`
LOG_FILE="/tmp/script_${CURR_DT}.log"
export PURGE_DIR_PATH="${WEB_HOME}/backup/csvs  ${WEB_HOME}/home/archives"


    for dir_name in ${PURGE_DIR_PATH}
      do
        echo "inside for loop"
        echo "dirname=${dir_name}"
        if [[ -d "${dir_name}" ]] 
        then
        echo "inside IF loop"
        echo "${dir_name} exists on the filesysetm." >> ${LOG_FILE}
        echo "csv Files older than ${LOG_RETENTION} days to be removed: " >> ${LOG_FILE}
          find ${dir_name}  -type f -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.log*" -mtime +${LOG_RETENTION} -exec ls -l {} \; >> ${LOG_FILE}
          #find ${dir_name}  -type f -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.log*" -mtime +${LOG_RETENTION} -exec rm | xargs rm {} \; >> ${LOG_FILE}
          echo "csv Files older than ${LOG_COMPRESS} to be compressed: " >> ${LOG_FILE}
          find ${dir_name}  -type f -name "*.csv"  -o -name "*.log*" -mtime +${LOG_COMPRESS} -exec ls -l {} \; >> ${LOG_FILE}
          #find ${dir_name}  -type f -name "*.csv"  -o -name "*.log*" -mtime +${LOG_COMPRESS} -exec gzip {} \;
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

First, the OR-clauses need to be wrapped in parens. The find command treats all conditions as ANDs. So try this:

```
find ${dir_name}  -type f \( -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.log*" \) -mtime +${LOG_RETENTION} -exec ls -l {} \; >> ${LOG_FILE}
```

Second, this line is malformed with an "-exec rm" and a pipe to xargs:

```
find ${dir_name}  -type f -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.log*" -mtime +${LOG_RETENTION} -exec rm | xargs rm {} \; >> ${LOG_FILE}
```

I suspect you meant something like this:

```
find ${dir_name}  -type f \( -name "*.csv" -o -name "*.log*" \) -mtime +${LOG_RETENTION} -print | xargs rm {} \;
```

And, one more thing... You might get the gzip balking at attempts to double compress *.log.gz files because of the trailing asterisk on this find:

```
find ${dir_name}  -type f \( -name "*.csv"  -o -name "*.log*" \) -mtime +${LOG_COMPRESS} -exec ls -l {} \; >> ${LOG_FILE}
```

It works for matching the old files that you want to delete, but for the compression step, you probably want: -name "*.log"

Comment: i have commented the lines which has rm in it, im still testing the first find command where it lists out all the files from both the directories, it is displaying files from one directory only, i have commented the line as you can see. Not sure whrere I'm going wrong

Comment: Also its displaying the files twice from the same directory . 16 files should have displayed but 32 are being displayed instead of picking from another directory

Comment: Answer updated with additional suggestions.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the finds are working but if i remove * after log its not compressing file for the following date format --> test.log.2021-04-15. If i put * , its giving error for other files, says file.gz already has .gz suffix. How can i handle this? Please let me know.                                                       
         find ${dir_name}  -type f \( -name "*.csv"  -o -name "*.log" \) -mtime +${LOG_COMPRESS} -exec ls -l {} \; >> ${LOG_FILE}